# Magento Local XML not called

Tags: theme, layout

I was wondering why my Magento local.xml is not being called. I have a package with multiple themes.

Package

- Default

  - /layout/local.xml
- Theme1

  - /layout/local.xml
- Theme2

  - /layout/local.xml

I'm using **Theme1** but the local.xml being called is from the Default theme. What I wanted was to use local.xml from Theme1. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Magento offers the possibility to use templates from one theme and layouts from an other one.
Even if this sounds nice, I don't think anyone uses it (I ma be wrong) because it can confuse the developers.
To avoid this, make sure that in `System->Configuration->Design->Themes` you set the same value for the fields `Templates` and `Layout`, the name of your theme.
If one of these is left blank the resources from the default theme will be used. (Theme1).

Comment: Thank you Marius for your reply. I've set the Templates, Skin, Layout to Theme1 but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: We use the type specific settings, but only for another fallback layer. I'm looking forward to limitless fallbacks in Magento 2. ;)

Comment: Hi David can you expound what you meant by type specific? Does this mean that only the layout.xml in the Default theme gets recognized? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have a local.xml file override for every theme directory - something is misconfigured **or you have an error in your local.xml file**.

[Validate your XML file here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

After you validate, you may want to turn on Magento Developer Mode to display future XML validation warnings.

http://alanstorm.com/magento_exception_handling_developer_mode

Aside from this, update the settings in `System > Configuration > Design > Themes` and point all of the field values to the same theme with the exception of `default`. Ensure that you have no values set under `System > Design` - which is meant to provide theme overrides on a scheduled basis (e.g. Holiday themes).