# 1.9 RWD Remove Newsletter from Footer

Tags: rwd-theme, newsletter, footer

I'm still figuring Magento out just wasted 2 hours searching how to remove the newsletter block from the footer in the RWD theme (I'm using a child theme of this).

Here is my app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/layout/local.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name></action>
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland-ie8.css</name></action>
    <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
    <action method="addlinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>css/custom.css</name></href></action>
    <action method="addlinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>css/what-we-buy.css</href></action>
</reference>

<reference name="footer">
    <remove name="footer.newsletter" />
    <remove name="footer_links" />
    <remove name="footer_links2" />
</reference>


</default>
</layout>
```

but nothing changes. I think everything in the 'head' section is applying since I do not see any of that when I ->view source. I even tried removing

```
    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="newsletter" before="footer_store_language" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

from newsletter.xml but even that doesn't work. I have flushed the cache multiple times as well. None of the other blocks remove from footer either.

So the question is, what am I not understanding and how do I remove the newsletter box from the footer in 1.9 RWD theme?

Edit: Added my local.xml info. Also, removing code directly from newseltter.xml (or page.xml for other footer blocks) does seem to work when cache is disabled. I know this is not the correct way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this answer to a user with related issue

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5535/21254

And it was an error in my xml! There was an extra  tag that shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml

and add the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
        <reference name="footer">
                <remove name="footer.newsletter" />
        </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

It may be that you were doing it in a XML file before the newsletter template had actually been loaded, or if you were doing it in a local.xml file you had the wrapper tags missing, but I've just verified on a clean install of 1.9 and it's working as it should.

Comment: Ahh sorry for not being more clear. My local.xml looks exactly like what you put, but does not effect anything. I have it in app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/layout/

Comment: Make sure you refresh the layout and block cache after making the change.

Comment: @k1rah - you say you've put it in rwd/mytheme - but have you then told Magento to use that theme? If you create your own design, you need to tell it to use that design rather than the default.

Take a quick look at http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-switch-your-store-to-default-theme.html to see how to change it.

Otherwise, if you have not told it to use a different design, then put the local file in the default directory as per my original answer.

Comment: Yes, I have done this. Package is set to rwd, and all the theme entries are set to my custom theme. It is only a very minor customized theme of rwd, but it seems nothing in the local.xml that I posted above is applying.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of Magento this was for but after I followed app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml on my 1.9.3.1 there was no local.xml but a bunch of other *.xml one named newslettter.xml. So after renaming that file the newsletter link was removed.